# Semantic Distance/Similarity between two terms in a sentence

Tags: nlp, semantics, text-mining, linguistics

I was wondering of anyone have a reference of information talking about semantic distance/similarity between 2 words in a sentence BASED on counting the words that separate between these 2 words? 
Example:

```
"The student went to the university to learn about the facts of life"
so if the distance threshold is 3 token then:
"student" and "university" will be connected by an edge (distance 3 words)
" facts and "life" will be connected by an edge (distance 1)
"student" and "Fact" will not be connected (distance 8) 
etc.
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'counting the words that separate between these 2 words'? Also provide an example, pls

Comment: updated the Q with example

Answer (score 0):

To find a semantic similarity between two words, the most simple algorithm would be to use a word lesk algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesk_algorithm), using wordnet. I doubt if there is any method of finding semantic similarity by the distance between the words.